# attempting to recreate supervisor tutorial in docker, running into error (permissioning?)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, docker, supervisord, coreos

I'm attempting to recreate the steps in [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps) in a docker context, ubuntu image installed under coreos running in virtualbox on OS X.

I've set up a Dockerfile that has the following steps:

```
# Install docker basics
RUN echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main universe" > /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

# Install supervisor
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor
RUN mkdir -p /var/run/sshd
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor
RUN mkdir -p /etc/supervisor/conf.d

# tutorial suite
ADD ./etc/long.sh /usr/local/bin/long.sh
RUN /bin/chmod 0777 /usr/local/bin/long.sh
ADD ./etc/long_script.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/long_script.conf

# create supervisord user
RUN /usr/sbin/useradd --create-home --home-dir /usr/local/nonroot --shell /bin/bash nonroot

# start supervisord
RUN sudo service supervisor start
```

which copies the following files out of a relative `/etc/` directory:

`long.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    # Echo current date to stdout
    echo `date`
    # Echo 'error!' to stderr
    echo 'error!' >&2
    sleep 1
done
```

and `long_script.conf`:

```
[program:long_script]
command=/usr/local/bin/long.sh
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/long.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/long.out.log
```

It loads everything correctly, but then there is no corresponding output in either `/var/log/long.out.log` or `/var/log/long.err.log`, although both files are present in that directory.

When I load the image with `/bin/bash`/, I then try the following:

1. I can successfully run `service supervisor restart` and get `Restarting supervisor:` as output.
2. But when I try to run any functions with `supervisorctl`, I get errors, i.e. `unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock refused connection`

I checked the output of `/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log` and it gives me:

```
2014-03-17 08:54:48,090 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2014-03-17 08:54:48,090 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/long_script.conf" during parsing
2014-03-17 08:54:48,161 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2014-03-17 08:54:48,161 WARN cElementTree not installed, using slower XML parser for XML-RPC
2014-03-17 08:54:48,161 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2014-03-17 08:54:48,163 INFO daemonizing the supervisord process
2014-03-17 08:54:48,164 INFO supervisord started with pid 10
2014-03-17 08:54:49,165 INFO spawned: 'long_script' with pid 13
[error] client.go:2296 Error resize: Error: resize: bad file descriptor
```

Googling suggests that I include a barebones `supervisord.conf` file that explicitly points the application to the `supervisord.sock` file, so I added the following to the Dockerfile:

```
# Add supervisor config file
ADD ./etc/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
```

and then added a `supervisord.conf` file that looks like this:

```
[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
loglevel=error
nodaemon=false

[supervisorctl]
serverurl = unix:///var/run/supervisord.sock
```

After including this

1. I no longer have either `long.err.log` or `long.out.log` populating in `/var/log/` at all.
2. I am able to run `service supervisor restart`, but now when I run `supervisorctl`, the error I get is changed to `unix:///var/run/supervisord.sock no such file`.

I checked the output of `/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log` and it gives me:

```
2014-03-17 08:48:29,715 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)[error] client.go:2296 Error resize: Error: resize: bad file descriptor
```

Thinking that this might be a user permissioning issue, I tried switching the `supervisord.conf` file to

```
[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
loglevel=error
nodaemon=false
user=nonroot

[supervisorctl]
serverurl = unix:///var/run/supervisord.sock
```

after adding the following to my `Dockerfile`

```
RUN /usr/sbin/useradd --create-home --home-dir /usr/local/nonroot --shell /bin/bash nonroot
```

but that gets me the following error on compile

```
Step XX : RUN service supervisor start
 ---> Running in fdcb12ff3cfa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/supervisord", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('supervisor==3.0a8', 'console_scripts', 'supervisord')()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/supervisor/supervisord.py", line 371, in main
go(options)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/supervisor/supervisord.py", line 381, in go
d.main()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/supervisor/supervisord.py", line 88, in main
info_messages)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/supervisor/options.py", line 1231, in make_logger
stdout = self.nodaemon,
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/supervisor/loggers.py", line 325, in getLogger
handlers.append(RotatingFileHandler(filename,'a',maxbytes,backups))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/supervisor/loggers.py", line 180, in __init__
FileHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/supervisor/loggers.py", line 106, in __init__
self.stream = open(filename, mode)
```

Logging into `/bin/bash/` and doing a `cat` on `/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log` now yields:

```
2014/03/17 08:57:36 build: The command [/bin/sh -c service supervisor start] returned a non-zero code: 1
2014-03-17 08:54:48,090 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2014-03-17 08:54:48,090 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/long_script.conf" during parsing
2014-03-17 08:54:48,161 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2014-03-17 08:54:48,161 WARN cElementTree not installed, using slower XML parser for XML-RPC
2014-03-17 08:54:48,161 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2014-03-17 08:54:48,163 INFO daemonizing the supervisord process
2014-03-17 08:54:48,164 INFO supervisord started with pid 10
2014-03-17 08:54:49,165 INFO spawned: 'long_script' with pid 13
[error] client.go:2296 Error resize: Error: resize: bad file descriptor
```

What is the issue here? I just want to be able to run this shell script via `supervisord` and observe its output in the log files.

Comment: looks like it might be related to [this issue](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/2683)?

Comment: [this issue](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/3485) suggests `RUN apt-get install cgroup-lite` to get rid of the "bad file descriptor" error. It does that, but the rest of the issues remain.

Comment: Why do you want to run supervisorctl? Are you going to use that when the image works as expected? Because it seems to me you're getting into a lot of new problems trying to debug your initial problem.
In case it helps you, I've written a blog on supervisor/Docker here: http://blog.trifork.com/2014/03/11/using-supervisor-with-docker-to-manage-processes-supporting-image-inheritance/

Answer (score 3):

You are also starting the service - but then not leaving it to run.

```
RUN sudo service supervisor start
```

You should probably be running it directly:

```
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

You may also have to/need to add some parameters to that CMD. See: [Docker/Supervisord example](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/examples/using_supervisord/)

Comment: this is getting closer, but I'm still having issues. I changed the Dockerfile to `CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]`; when I run `sudo docker run -t -i {username}/{image}` I get no output, as expected, but then  `sudo docker run -t -i {username}/{image} bin/bash` followed by `supervisorctl` errors out that the socket file hasn't been created (and no logs are created). `/usr/bin/supervisord` locally inside the bash terminal and then `supervisorctl` runs w expected output. clearly this is an issue between the versions of `{username}/{image}` as I'm running them but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I also had this issue and `sudo` wasn't helping. So, instead of using unix sockets, I'm just using the tcp sockets instead:

```
[inet_http_server]
port=:9001
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface
[supervisorctl]
serverurl=http://localhost:9001
```

You can also bind just to localhost (`127.0.0.1:9001`) and add an optional user and password.

Comment: A combination of this and fixing the location of my config file (from "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf" to "/etc/supervisor.conf") worked for me.  Thanks!

Comment: Yep, forgot to mention that. The above config should go in `/etc/supervisor.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a dated question. However I'm posting since you haven't accept an answer yet. When working with docker and supervisor, make sure to run supervisord in foreground. You can do it by changing your supervisord.conf. Set

```
nodaemon=true
```

Comment: If you scan the OP, you'll see that I added that to the `.conf` file. Thank you, though.